# SeleniumBase and Datadome

Tags: seleniumbase

I am trying (still) to overcome datadome detection with SeleniumBase in UC mode. I thought i had it, but it seems like datadome is evolving and now throws me to the captcha and after i slide the jigsaw piece by hand i get blocked. I have attached the code in case someone can see what i might have left out. You'll notice some sleeps and pyautogui movements of the cursor to try to look more like a human - prior versions (that were also rejectd) did not have these lines. Thanks in advance for any ideas.(not sure why spacing is a little off, but it's fine in pycharm code)

```
with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    #   Maximize window size
    sb.maximize_window()
    #   Open up LOG IN screen
    #   REMOVED FOR A LITTLE ANONIMITY
    #   Accept cookies settings
    sleep(2)
    sb.click('button:nth-child(1)')
    #   Find Username field and enter it using stored value from credentials array
    sleep(2)
    sb.type("#p_lt_ContentWidgets_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneContent_CHO_Widget_"\
        "LoginFormWith"\
        "FullscreenBackground_XLarge_loginCtrl_BaseLogin_UserName", credentials[0][0])

    #   Find/enter user password
    sleep(2)
    sb.type('#p_lt_ContentWidgets_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneContent_CHO_Widget_'
        'LoginFormWith'\
        'FullscreenBackground_XLarge_loginCtrl_BaseLogin_Password', credentials[0][1])
    sleep(2)
    sb.click("#p_lt_ContentWidgets_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneContent_CHO_Widget_"
         "LoginFormWithFullscreen"\
        "Background_XLarge_loginCtrl_BaseLogin_LoginButton")
    sleep(5)
    #     print("MSG035 Unable to Select LOG ON Button")
    print("Title = ", sb.get_title())
    #
    pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)
    sb.click("#p_lt_ContentWidgets_pageplaceholder_p_lt_zoneSM30_CHO_Widget_"\
        "QuickLinkMenu"\
        "_Small_rptItems_ctl03_hrefLink")

    #   Switch Focus to new window - leave original window to preserve session

    sb.switch_to_newest_window()
    pyautogui.moveTo(525, 121)
    #   Move down 
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(534, 155, 1)
    pyautogui.click()

    pyautogui.moveTo(525, 121)
    #   Move down to make/change tee times
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(534, 155, 1)
    print("Drop Down")
    #   Select/hover over the  Button after sleeping for 3 seconds
    sleep(3)
    #sb.slow_click("span:nth-child(1)")
    sb.slow_click('//*[@id="rwdNav"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span')
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(534, 155, 1)
    #   Select option
    print("Select drop down option")
   sleep(3)
    sb.slow_click("li:nth-child(1)")
    sleep(10)
    sb.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the default `reconnect_time` isn't enough in SeleniumBase UC Mode when going to a site that takes a longer time to load. You can customize that. Here's an example script that did that at the beginning:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, incognito=True, test=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://pixelscan.net/", 11)
    sb.remove_elements("jdiv")  # Remove chat widgets
    sb.assert_text("No automation framework detected", "pxlscn-bot-detection")
    sb.assert_text("You are not masking your fingerprint")
    sb.highlight("span.text-success", loops=10)
    sb.sleep(1)
    sb.highlight("pxlscn-fingerprint-masking div", loops=10, scroll=False)
    sb.sleep(1)
    sb.highlight("div.bot-detection-context", loops=10, scroll=False)
    sb.sleep(3)
```

If mixing SeleniumBase UC Mode with `pyautogui`, first call this before running `pyautogui` commands:

```py
driver.disconnect()
```

And then when done with `pyautogui` commands, call this to use Selenium again:

```py
driver.connect()
```

Note that if you did everything correctly, you might not even need to use `pyautogui` at all.

Comment: Michael - I appreciate your continued answers to my questions. I copied your code and ran it through pycharm and got the following error message:  AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'uc_open_with_reconnect' What am i missing???  I just copied and pasted code...

Comment: Are you sure you copied the `uc=True` part?

Comment: First few lines - too many characters if i copy all of it:                                                           from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, incognito=True, test=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect("https://pixelscan.net/", 11)
    sb.remove_elements("jdiv")  # Remove chat widgets

Comment: Run the script as is. https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/raw_pixelscan.py is working for me. If any issues, just use `uc=True` for args.

Comment: i have tried a few approaches including copying and pasting from the site you passed on. Not sure why, but i keep getting the AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'uc_open_with_reconnect'. I certainly can't explain what's going on. Maybe some library issue???

Comment: Use “uc=True” with SeleniumBase to get the UC Mode methods.